# What was the tower seen in stage 3 of Tour de France on Corsica?

Tags: france, identify-this, mediterranean, corsica

Stage 3 of this year's Tour de France passed an tower at the end of a headland on the Corsican Coast. Anyone recognise it? According to Wikipedia there are 90 towers on Corsica!

Seen here (UK) about two minutes in https://www.itv.com/itvplayer/tour-de-france/series-21/episode-4

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This looks like one of the [Genoese towers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Genoese_tower), of which [67 still stand today](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_des_tours_g%C3%A9noises_en_Corse). They are somewhat similar-looking and all are on the seacoast, so it may be a bit difficult to identify this particular tower without a doubt. You can compare the [map of surviving towers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File%3aCorse-tours_g%C3%A9noises.JPG) with the [route followed by the Tour](http://www.depart-tdf-corse2013.com/fr/les-etapes/) — that only eliminates about half of them.

[Tour de la Parata](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File%3aAjaccio_TG2_JPG.jpg) in Ajaccio looks very similar, so I guess that's the one. It's also one of the most famous ones. It's a local [tourist attraction](http://www.ajaccio.fr/La-Parata-Portrait-du-site_a73.html).